# Apache ignite filtering query by date

Tags: sql, ignite

In my cache class I have my **factorDate** as a **Joda DateTime** object

```
@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private DateTime factorDate;
```

I need to get all the results between 2 dates. To achieve this I have the following code:

```
    CacheConfiguration<Integer, MyClass> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("myCache");
    cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, MyClass.class);

    IgniteConfiguration ignitionConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
    ignitionConfig.setCacheConfiguration(cfg);
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(ignitionConfig);

    IgniteCache<Integer, MyClass> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);

    DateTime startDateObj = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").parseDateTime(startDate);
    DateTime endDateObj = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").parseDateTime(endDate);

    Timestamp startTimeStamp = new Timestamp(startDateObj.getMillis());
    Timestamp endTimeStamp = new Timestamp(endDateObj.getMillis());

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(" SELECT factorDate, name FROM MyClass ");
    builder.append(" WHERE factorDate >= ? AND factorDate <= ? ");
    builder.append(" AND name = ? ");

    SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery(builder.toString());

    qry.setArgs(startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp, "Jack Jones");
    List<List<?>> res = cache.query(qry).getAll();
```

I get no results back when I know there are results. Any ideas?

I have also tried using the **DateTime object instead of timestamp as the query argument** but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default binary format doesn't support custom `Comparable` classes. As a workaround you can try to use `OptimizedMarshaller` instead:

```
<property name="marshaller">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller"/>
</property>
```

But note that it will deserialize your keys and values on server nodes, so you have to make sure that classes are deployed there.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the second part please?

Comment: Ignite stores data in binary format by default. It allows to run SQL queries without deserialization (that's why `Comparable` is ignored as well). If `OptimizedMarshaller` is used, objects will be deserialized on server side and these deserialized objects will be used to get field values.